# Can I add a custom/email domain column in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Sometimes in Outlook I want to be able to see the last few emails I received or sent to a client.

As there can be several individual email addresses per client, the only way to reliably identify emails as belonging to a client is to look at the domain part of the email address, eg the `company` in `person@company.com`

How can I add this as a sortable column in the main views (`Inbox`, `Sent Items`, etc)?

Answer (score 4):

Almost found what I want from [here](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/sort-messages-sender-domain/) (I've improved on the formula).

Add a new column to a view from the `Show Columns` dialog, click `New Column` and enter a new formula based column:

```
IIf(InStr([SearchFromEmail], "@") = 0, "", Mid([SearchFromEmail], InStr([SearchFromEmail], "@") + 1))
```

Similar question was asked here https://superuser.com/questions/703013/outlook-how-to-display-sender-email-address-in-inbox/703035#703035

Comment: The problem with this method is that these custom column are not sortable of filterable. Outlook will only filter/sort on columns that return an intrinsic data element that is part of the stored Item (e.g. the "From", "To", "Received" etc.). To make a custom column that Oultook will sort, you have to create a new Item Property and add it to the Item. You can use VBA to extract text from the original Item, then apply it as a property, then add a column to display that property. Very annoying, given this idea is pretty basic...

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. You can process all your existing emails (and automatically process all new items using `MAPIFolder.Items.ItemAdd` event on the folders that you want to process) to set a user property (`MailItem.UserProperties.Add`) to the value extracted by your code. If you modify the folder views to include your property, you will be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Items class is not fired when multiple items are added to the folder at the same time.

You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Application class which is fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method and process the item.

In the event handler you can add a user property which can be user in the UI for sorting items (`MailItem.UserProperties.Add`). The [CurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864212.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the Folder class returns a [View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864185.aspx) object representing the current view.

The `View` object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.
 - The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
 - The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
 - The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
 - The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
 - The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868419.aspx) property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.